# How does Impedance matching equation work out from original link?

Tags: voltage, impedance, voltage-divider, impedance-matching, equation

From this link: [L-Pad Impedance Matching Equation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/459018/l-pad-impedance-matching-equation/496826?noredirect=1#comment1267273_496826)

How do you get those two equations? They do not look like a voltage divider formula, do they?

**Questions repeated here:**

[image]

**First answer from Adil Malik:**

Say
R1=475,R2=56.2,Rload=50,Rsource=500

You simply want from the source side:
R1+(R2∗Rload)/(R2+Rload)=Rsource

So lets try that:
475+(50∗56.5)/(50+56.5)=501.5

So this shows that it works.

But as you can see there are 2 unknowns, ie
R1
and
R2
. So you need atleast two equations. The one I did above was looking in from the source side. You can form a similar equation from the load side and solve simultaneously:

R2||(R1+Rsource)=Rload

Comment: Hi. Maybe repeat the circuit in your question in case the original changes.

Comment: At RJR, your comments accepted. Done.

Answer (score 0):

They're basic series and parallel impedance combinations, based on the fact that the impedance looking into a transmission line terminated with its characteristic impedance is equal to the characteristic impedance.

Comment: Thank you, Photon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: "Resistances in series and parallel."

Consider the 56.2Ω resistor.  It is in parallel with the 50Ω impedance presented by the transmission line.  Resistances in parallel are equivalent to Requiv = R1R2/(R1+R2).  Thus the 56.2Ω and the 50Ω together act as (56.2)(50)/(56.2+50) = 26.46Ω.  Thus the input sees the input resistor 475Ω in series with this 26.46Ω which is 501.46Ω which I suppose is close enough for the purposes of that post.

To derive the formulas, replace "56.2" with (variable) "R1" and "50" with "Z" (where I am using "Z" to represent the impedance of the transmission line).  The 475Ω resistor -- call it R2.  Introduce a 4th variable (say Zi) to represent the final input impedance (in that case, 500Ω).

The rest is algebra; solve for R1 and R2 in terms of Z and Zi.  Two equations, two unknowns.

Also be aware that the value [ab / (a+b)] is equal to [ 1 / (1/a + 1/b) ] as you can easily verify.

Comment: Hi Atomique, your answer is very helpful. Keep this up, helping with this forum here.